# jQuery's .clone(true, true) not cloning event bindings on children

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm using clone(true, true) to copy a select and some buttons to clone and remove.
I thought the second true argument should ensure that the event handler is passed on to the cloned child buttons.

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="clone-container">
    <div class="clone">
        <label for="select1">Select 1</label>
        <select id="select1" name="select1" class="">
            <option>Select One:</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
        <span class="controls">
            <a href="#" class="btn add">+</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn remove">−</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And the js:

```
var $cloned = $('.clone').clone(true, true);
var $addButton = $(".btn.add");
$addButton.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");    
    $cloned.clone().insertAfter($cloner);
});​
```

And here is a js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cjmemay/yXA4R/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The original clone (`$cloned`) does not have an event listener bound to the button
2. Your second invocation of `clone` does not preserve events

You need to clone the container *after* you have attached the event listener to the button. Additionally, you need to pass the `true` arguments to the second invocation of `clone`:

```
var $addButton = $(".btn.add");
$addButton.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");    
    $cloned.clone(true, true).insertAfter($cloner);
});
var $cloned = $('.clone').clone(true, true);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/3hjfj/

Comment: I knew about the second clone, that was just an accident, but that makes perfect sense about cloning after binding. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> You can use jQuery.detach() instead .clone(true,true);
>
> That will be copy element with events and everything

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having problems with losing events on a scroller and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/aT5mV/1/

I have modified the `on` event to catch all clicks on `.btn.add`, dynamically elements created included.

```
var $cloned = $('.clone').clone();

$('#clone-container').on("click", '.btn.add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $cloner = $(this).closest(".clone");    
    $cloned.clone().insertAfter($cloner);
});
​
```

Comment: I was aware of this option, but hadn't gotten it to work. I'll accept it if nothing better comes up, but would prefer to understand why .clone(true, true) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning the second time using `.clone(true,true)` too

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that. I've updated the js fiddle to show that.