# How to make cloned elements change its associated (clone) relatives

Tags: jquery, html

First of all, I'm sorry if my English were so bad. I'll try to explain it as clearly as possible.

I have a dynamic table, whose row can be added through the use of `clone()` function. Inside the row, there is a `<select>` which triggers change to "Respond" column.

I'm trying to figure out how to make a `.clone()` row to only change their respective Respond column.

The current state is, every time I make changes to the cloned rows, it will change its predecessor (real) row.

For my reference, I've read one of the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113029/jquerys-clonetrue-true-not-cloning-event-bindings-on-children)

Here's my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/joo_nath/fr5utycL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have more than one element with the same `id`, this is your issue. If you use classes to attach you click events then you will be OK.

You also need to help the code limit it's actions to elements with that class, but only in that row. I have changed your `id` to a `class` for each of the copied UI components and also added the lines below on click of the `select`

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".responder").text("Emakk!!");
```

**Explaination of the code**

- `$(this)` start with the element that has been clicked
- `.closest("tr")` move up the DOM tree until you find the first `tr` element
- `.find(".responder")` search the DOM tree children of the current element (which is now the closest `tr`) for any element with the class `.responder`
- `.text("Emakk!!")` change the text of any elements that match the current selection

---

## Demo

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".addItPlease").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var clone = $(this).closest("#bodyTab");
     cloned.clone(true).insertAfter(clone);
   });

   $(".switch").change(function() {
     $(this).each(function() {
       if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() == 1) {
         $(this).closest("tr").find(".responder").text("Babeh!!");
       } else if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() == 2) {
         $(this).closest("tr").find(".responder").text("Emakk!!");
       }
     });
   });
   var cloned = $("#bodyTab").clone(true, true);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container p-5 m-5">
  <table class="table table-light table-striped table-hover" id="iniTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Choice</th>
        <th>Respond</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="bodyTab">
      <tr>
        <td id="selector">
          <select class="switch">
      <option value="1">Bapak</option>
      <option value="2">Ibu</option>
      <option value="3">Abang</option>
     </select>
        </td>
        <td class="responder">dsad</td>
        <td id="smh">
          <a class="btn btn-success p-3 text-white addItPlease" href="#" id="">Tambah</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, Thank you so much! So glad there's always be people like you here sir

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer and vote up if it worked. Good luck with your project!